# Makefile check existence of variable from list

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile:

```
#Build Configurations
CONFIGS = Debug Release Profile

#Config flags
Debug_Flags=dasd
Release_Flags=

.SECONDEXPANSION:

#Debug_safety_check Release_safety_check Profile_safety_check targets
$(addsuffix _safety_check,$(CONFIGS)):
#Check existence of variable
ifeq '$(origin $(subst safety_check,FLAGS,$@))' 'undefined'
    $(error $(subst safety_check,FLAGS,$@) variable undefined)
endif 

#How to make our configurations (do corresponding safety_checks)
$(CONFIGS): $$@_safety_check
```

This line is incorrect:

```
ifeq '$(origin $(subst safety_check,FLAGS,$@))' 'undefined'
```

I think, It is because **$@** expansion occurs, when calling corresponding safety check. But ifeq expansion occurs "immediately", so, in fact, we get such line:

```
ifeq '$(origin ' ') 'undefined'
```

Does some method of check variables definition from list exist?

Comment: This... is really confused, and you're using `SECONDEXPANSION` when it isn't called for. Which variables do you want to check?

Comment: @Beta, **.SECONDEXPANSION** used in line `$(CONFIGS): $$@_safety_check `. Isn't it? I've found the solution some hours ago. Wait a minute, I'll post it.

Comment: @Beta, I would check variables `Release_Flags` and `Debug_Flags`. At all `$(addsuffix _Flags, $(CONFIGS))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ufff, gotcha.

```
#Build Configurations
CONFIGS = Debug Release Profile

#Config flags
Debug_Flags=dasd
Release_Flags=
#Profile_Flags=

#Adds _flags suffix for each variable, 
#get it's origin ('undefined' for undefined variables).
#If $(findstring) a lookup for the word 'undefined' succeeds, 
#adds to the result variable
undef_flags = $(foreach c, $(CONFIGS), \
                $(if $(findstring undefined, $(origin $c_Flags)), $c))

#Count words for undefined configs, must be not '0'
ifneq ($(words $(undef_flags)),0)
#strip because if flag is undefined we'll get the trash spaces
$(error Flags ($(strip $(undef_flags))) must be defined)
endif
```